# c# api status: what should be status and exception if we get null response from some intermediate service required to process api request

Tags: c#, api, http, exception, status

We have an API that sends SMS to the users. In the SMS content, we need to send the tinyUrl.We have external service that return us the shortUrl i.e.

```
string shortUrl = UrlShortenerService.GetShortUrl(longUrl);
```

What should be status code returned to the client if I get null shortUrl from this service response. What should be the exception type?

The API is not just responsible to send the shortUrl but to send this shortUrl to user's mobile so we can't return 2xx status as the request was not fulfilled, we can't send 4xx request as there was nothing wrong in client's request.

Comment: if it is returning a null, I think it would be a 200 OK code because it reached the api and returned a null?

Comment: @Haris sorry, updated the question now. Can't return 200 as the API is not responsible just to send the shortened url but to send this short url to users.

Comment: If you really want to give a http error code i guess `500` for internal server fault.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a 503. It's an error caused by the external service. Or if you want to be more general you can use the 500 status code

Comment: 503 is used when the requested http request is to busy right?

Comment: yes it is, but I think in this case it's not the worst choice, because the client doesn't know why the service is unavailable and a retry is recommended